How to show toast message after adding pinned shortcut on Kotlin/Android?
I have managed to create a pinned shortcut with Kotlin, however when I run "createshortcut", I am getting pop up "pixel launcher", with 2 buttons "cancel" and "add to home". How can I make it that when I click "add to home" after this action to run a toast message "Shortcut successfully added".
I can only figure out how to run toast message on the createshortcut function, but cannot grasp my head around where is the pixel launcher coming from and how to modify it/aka run toast only after clicking add to home?
Thank you!
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private fun createShortcut(shortcutName: String, shortcutId: Int) {
        val shortcutManager = getSystemService(ShortcutManager::class.java)
        if (shortcutManager?.isRequestPinShortcutSupported == true) {
            val shortcutIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java).apply {
                action = Intent.ACTION_RUN
                putExtra("route", "editNoteScreen")
                putExtra("shortcutClicked", true)
                putExtra("shortcutId", shortcutId)
            }
            val shortcutInfo = ShortcutInfo.Builder(this, shortcutId.toString())
                .setShortLabel(shortcutName)
                .setLongLabel(shortcutName)
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(this, R.drawable.ic_shortcut_icon))
                .setIntent(shortcutIntent)
                .build()

            val pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent = shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(shortcutInfo)

            val pendingIntentFlags = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE
            } else {
                0
            }

            val successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                this,
                0,
                pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent,
                pendingIntentFlags
            )

            shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(shortcutInfo, successCallback.intentSender)
        }
    }

I tried adding print statement all throughout my mainactivity code, and "add to home" triggers none of it. It does add home shortcut though
